# Windows batch script play MP3 files daily

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am working on a problem where I need to play an MP3 file twice a day, and then iterate to another file an so on for a 96 day cycle. The day 1 file will play at 6 am and then again at 6 pm.  The following day the day 2 file will play at the same times.  The cycle will continue until day 96 when the process will start back at day 1.

I would like the script to read the day value from a separate text file and then start the process from there.  The text file would just contain the starting number, then would be updated on each iteration.

I will be using Windows task manager to schedule the bat file execution times.

Any help is appreciated, let me know if you need more specifics or context.

Comment: and where you face a problem? running the .mp3 file? iterate the list with the mp3 files? getting the current hour?

Comment: though - here's a script that will run an mp3 file from command line without external tools - https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/mediarunner.bat

Comment: Problem comes with putting everything together, I can play an MP3 file, but cannot store and read a variable from text file, and then iterate.

Comment: You need to keep running that batch script for a whole day!

Comment: @darkfang: Why that? Running it twice a day with a scheduled task and storing progress in a textfile will work fine. Sadly, the OP didn't show us his attempts, so we have no basis to help him.

Comment: So here is the program I ended up with, the only problem now is how do I make it so the file only plays once....or turns off Media Player somehow?